# Zombie.js - Test if object property found

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, zombie.js

*Im a bit new of Zombie.js testing, and hard to search so I will ask here ...*

**Example :** *(Globla variable)*

```
hello = {"world" : "...."}
```

**So I test something like :**

```
describe('Check varibles', function() {
    it('If ---> hello <--- exits', function(done) {
        browser.assert.global('hello');
        done();
    });

    it('If ---> hello.world <--- exits', function(done) {
        // ????
        done();
    });
});
```

I can check if `hello` is exits. **But how to check** if hello.world` is exits ?

**I tried with :**

```
browser.assert.global('hello.world'); // AssertionError: undefined == true
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got an alternative *(use `assert` directly)*

**First : require `assert`**

```
const assert = require('assert');
```

**So do something like :**

```
it('If ---> hello.world <--- exits', function(done){
   assert.ok(browser.window.hello.world);
   //assert.ok(!browser.window.hello.world); <-- or check if not exits
   done();
});
```